# Is there a way to clear focus of input fields in webview

Tags: android, webview

I use Webview in android ,and clearFocus() not working,Is there a way to clear focus of input fields in webview?

Comment: have you tried this ? webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

Comment: Thanks for the reply i will try that and see

Answer (score 2):

You can try this might be help you

```
webView.clearFocus();
```